# How getting an array of xml file from android resource?

Tags: android, xml, resources, android-resources

I have this array into my resource file :

```
<array name="xml_data">
    <item>@xml/data1</item>
    <item>@xml/data2</item>
    <item>@xml/data3</item>
    <item>@xml/data4</item>
</array>
```

Normally, it's not different from an normal array, but when getting in code, this doesn't work...

```
final Resources res = getResources();
int[] xmlList = res.getIntArray(R.array.xml_data);
Log.i(TAG, "Data found: "+ xmlList.length);
for (int i = 0; i < xmlList.length; i++) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Extract xml id="+ xmlList[i].);
}
```

Here is the output obtained in the logcat :

```
Data found: 4
Extract xml id=0
Extract xml id=0
Extract xml id=0
Extract xml id=0
```

Can you help me about this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For your convenience lets take an example:

I had a simple 'string' array( not int) in a sample xml file. Lets call it array.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<resources>
<string-array name="doing">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2/item>
    <item>3/item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Now in my Java file, I called it as follows inside my OnCreate() function and it worked:

```
String[] xmlList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.doing);
int first = Integer.parseInt(xmlList[0]);
Log.d("test", "1st string is: " + first);
```

P.S: I haven't tested the code but I hope you got the logic. All the best. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use your TypedArray like this:

`TypedArray mTypedArray = getResources().getTypedArray(R.array.xml_data);`

Then, retrieve your resource ID's like this:

`int id = mTypedArray.getResourceId(position, defaultResourceId);`

When I used this, it was an array of String IDs, so I followed that with this:

`getString(id)`